# QGIS does not know PostGIS view id

Tags: qgis

I try to load views from PostGIS in QGIS 2.18 and I have discovered that QGIS does not recognize the id field of the view and must be set manually. How could I correct this[image]

Comment: Check option: Also list table with no geometry...?

Comment: I would upgrade to QGIS 3

Comment: I will upgrade to qgis 3.4 to try